# About the Handle in .Sortable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler, jquery-ui-sortable

When we use ref= as idenficatation, we wrote it lkie $([ref=Hadle_Here]).

In sortable(), to determine the specific area, use handle: XXXXX.

The problem in this handle: part, if I use class to define, like '.Hadle_Here', this will work. However, if I use '[ref=Hadle_Here]', this will return error.

Is this about it can not use or just I wrote it wrong???? Please advice.

```
$(XXXXX).sortable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursor: 'move', 
    cancel: 'input',
    handle: ////HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!
    update: function() {} 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
handle: $('[ref=xxxx]')
```

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/AuV3R/).